# SIM state detection issue on LG-P500

Tags: android, sim-card, lg

My app needs to check SIM card status before performing an action. So for that I use the TelephonyManager.getSimState () . If app see state as SIM_STATE_READY then it proceeds else show error to the user. 
This so far has worked well, but recently I got complains from LG-P500 (LG Optimus One ) device owners saying that although user has SIM card inserted in device and is able to make/receive calls my application keeps giving error about SIM card.

Logs from user shows that on device I get sim state as  SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN (0) .

```
OS Version :2.3.3
Brand :lge
Device :thunderg
```

Is LG any way managing Sim state differently or LG somehow treats SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN and SIM_STATE_READY  same ?

Thanks,

Tushar

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with only LG P500 since 2.3, on 2.2 works fine.
To detect if SIM ready you can use

`TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String imsi = tm.getSubscriberId();`

if imsi is not null SIM is ready.

Also on LG P500 works PhoneStateListener and you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

The doc says

> public static final int SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN
>
> SIM card state: Unknown. Signifies that the SIM is in transition
>   between states. For example, when the user inputs the SIM pin under
>   PIN_REQUIRED state, a query for sim status returns this state before
>   turning to SIM_STATE_READY.

SIM_STATE_READY is not equal to SIM_STATE_UNKNOW

Reason for showing unknown could be many. Also, chances are that it is in CDMA network hence might not have SIM or Access to it.